# Which electrons are in HOMO in a peptide bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

We've recently studied the absorption of UV light by polypeptides, and found that the peptide bonds itself absorhs UV light at around 210nm. I'm confused about what feature causes this to happen.

Comment: What question are you asking? Your title is asking about the HOMO and the body is asking about absorption. Yes they are related, but you need to flesh out the link.

Comment: The title is even not really clear as well having profound implications. You should reformulate the question entirely.